# juju message: Waiting for agent initialization to finish

Tags: juju, maas, openstack

juju deploy wordpress

juju deploy mysql

juju add-relation wordpress mysql

juju expose wordpress

```
juju status

environment: maas

      machines:
      "0":
agent-state: started
agent-version: 1.25.5.1
dns-name: original-shade.default
instance-id: /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-a20a8d58-12ff-11e6-b60a-525400717c8f/
series: trusty
hardware: arch=amd64 cpu-cores=24 mem=16384M availability-zone=default
state-server-member-status: has-vote

services:

mysql:
charm: cs:trusty/mysql-38
exposed: false
service-status:
  current: unknown
  message: Waiting for agent initialization to finish
  since: 05 May 2016 21:41:23-07:00
relations:
  cluster:
  - mysql
wordpress:
charm: cs:trusty/wordpress-4
exposed: false
service-status:
  current: unknown
  message: Waiting for agent initialization to finish
  since: 05 May 2016 21:47:37-07:00
relations:
  loadbalancer:
  - wordpress
```

Also no wordpress public address.......

current: unknown

message: Waiting for agent initialization to finish

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you deploy a service and don't specify a machine, juju deploys that service to a new machine enlisted in MAAS. This message appears when juju is grabbing a new node to deploy that service on.
[See juju deploy in commands list](https://jujucharms.com/docs/1.25/commands)